# How to Fake this get property into one of my controller tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

ignore everything

ignore everything

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
```

ignore everything
        public UserIdentity => User.Identity as ;

```
    public int UserId => Int32.Parse(Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
}
```

*This is my class*

Comment: Both UserId,UserIdentity are only get properties

Comment: Create a fake principal and give that to the controller before exercising the unit test

Comment: @Nkosi - Do you want me to add the fake principal to controller which i am unit testing?

Comment: Create instance of principle and assign it to controllers user property before running test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a fake principal and give that to the controller before exercising the unit test

```
[TestMethod()]
public void BaseController_When_Authenticated_Should_Return_UserId() {
    //Arrange
    //Create test user
    var expected = 12345;

    var identity = new LtfClaimsIdentity("Ltf"); // Or how ever it is you initialize your identity
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, expected.ToString()));

    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    // Set the User on the controller directly
    var controller = new BaseController () {
        User = user
    };

    //Act
    var actual = controller.UserId;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: UserId throws system null reference exception error and here is my LtfClaimsIdentityclass

Comment: public static class LtfClaimTypes
 {
  public const string SsoId = "http://schemas.ltfinc.net/ws/identity/claims/ssoid";
 }

 public class LtfClaimsIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
 {
  public LtfClaimsIdentity(string authenticationType) : base(authenticationType)
  { }

  public virtual string SsoId
  {
   // just an accessor for getting the SsoId claim
   get
   {
    var claim = FindFirst(LtfClaimTypes.SsoId);
    return claim?.Value;
   }
  }

Comment: Put the code in the original post. It will help improve your question.

Comment: I still get a null reference exception error at controller.UserId

Comment: @Keys using the new information you provided I was able to recreate the null reference exception and provide an update to my answer. I was able to test it and it worked. Pass the identity directly to the claims principle in the test.

Comment: Thanks!!. That really helped